# Trouble with string translations

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

I'm writing a question type plugin and I'm having trouble getting string translation to work. Instead of the string I specified, it shows [[answerheader]].

I'm calling the get_string() function like this:

```
$mform->addElement('header','answerheader',
                   get_string('answerheader','qtype_'.$this->qtype()));
```

and I have the matching entry in the localization file (qtype_mypluginname.php):

```
$string['answerheader'] = 'Answers';
```

but I get an error saying

```
Invalid get_string identifier: 'answerheader' or component 'qtype_mypluginname'. Perhaps
you are missing $string['answerheader'] = ''; in
c:\wamp64\www\moodle-plugin-dev/question/type/mypluginname/lang/en/qtype_mypluginname.php?
```

I have a method that returns the qtype in edit_mypluginname_form.php.

This is the first plugin I've written, and I've been using an included plugin as a guide. I set the plugin name to mypluginname at the end of edit_mypluginname_form.php; is there anything else I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried purging the site caches (or bumping the plugin version number and visiting notifications) in order to get Moodle to load the new strings?